# Very long request time VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have at small web-application that get some data from a SQLdb in Visual Studio 2010. When i try to display this, using a simple dropdownlist it takes around 15 sec the first time just after compilation and then after that 5 sec every request. I use a LINQ connection to db and a repeater to print everything out. It´s four columns and around 50 rows, so not so mutch data. It doesn´t matter if i try take 10 rows, same response time.

We have tested the same thing on another computer with VS2008 installed and the time was like 0.1 sec or something like that. I use .NET 3.5 and have installed all the latest updates (SP1 and so).

If i look at the trace i see it takes time at these rows in my code:

```
var cust = dbContext.Customers
    .Select(c => new
    {
        c.customerID,
        c.Email
    }).Take(10);

repeater.DataSource = cust;
repeater.DataBind();
```

Anybody know what could be taking som mutch time?

Regards
Daniel

I have tried this other aproach:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //default

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email FROM Customer";

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
```

It takes just as long.. there must be some other more fundamental problem than the code to call the db i think?

Some more information:
I did som trace, this is first time page is loaded:

```
Begin Raise ChangedEvents   0,00219604937555932 0,000014
After repeater has printed  15,8138335259613    15,811637
End Raise ChangedEvents 15,8138801733289    0,000047
```

Second time:

```
Begin Raise ChangedEvents   0,00219604937555932 0,000014
After repeater has printed  5,25090396258066    5,248825
End Raise ChangedEvents 25095106283536          0,000047
```

What´s happening at ChangeEvents?

Comment: Did you try calling ToList() after Take() ?

Comment: Did you check the database server to see how long the query is taking?

Comment: As an aside, I would name `cust` something more meaningful like `customerEmailQuery` and move the `.Take(10);` to the data binding line. It's important to make a clear distinction between variables that represent a linq query, and variables that are the result of the query.

Comment: It could also be the initial asp.net start up - are you hosting the web site in IIS on your VS2010 machine? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221292/asp-net-application-runs-slow-at-first-time for example.

Comment: @dash: i am hosting on my VS2010 machine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idee what i did to make it work.. just kept on doing stuff at other places in the code and updated latest windows update.. hmm.. now it work like a charm, must be a bug in VS2010?? 
Thanks for all suggestions though, learned some great stuff!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Get the actual SQL being generated by LINQ, copy-paste it to your database management tool and look at the execution plan to identify potential performance issues.

You can see the actual SQL by using [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property of the data context. In a console application, you can do this:

```
dbContext.Log = Console.Out;
// ...
```

Or, write the SQL to file like this:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("sql.log")) {
    dbContext.Log = writer;
    // ....
}
```

Also, it might be worth adding `ToList()` or `ToArray()` at the end of your LINQ expression, just to make sure it is not unintentionally re-executed.

Comment: There can´t be any wrong with the query i think, though it work fine on another computer with vs2008...